# Count string lengths in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am exploring a large dataframe with an object (string) column (air) of varying lengths such as this small example.

```
aic
12345678
87654321
123456789
1234
```

I want to obtain a summary of the count of each string length such as for the example:

```
length  count
4       1
8       2
9       1
```

I tried with

```
df["aic"].str.len().nunique()
```

which returns 3 meaning there are two different lengths but I don't know which.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
out = df.aic.astype(str).str.len().value_counts().reset_index()
Out[104]: 
   index  aic
0      8    2
1      9    1
2      4    1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you expand on the need of using reset_index and as type(str) given that dataframe column is already object type?

Comment: @RobertAlexander for me that is just a protection , reset_index is convert from series to data frame